# Interchange Item position of anonymous type

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities, anonymous-types

I have populated a sorted list of anonymous type using the following code.

```
var list = service.GetTenantsOverview()
                  .TenantsOverview
                  .Cast<TenantOverview>()
                  .Select(t => new { t.TenantId, t.Tenantnumber })
                  .OrderBy(t => t.Tenantnumber)
                  .ToList();
```

The problem is, I need to move the 3rd item to the 1st position. That means, I want to move the Tenantnumber "Any" to the 1st position. But didn't find any appropriate method to do that.

[image: Anonymous type list generated and sorted]

For the solution, I have made up the below code.

```
var item = list.First(f => f.Tenantnumber == "Any");
        list.Remove(item);
        list.Insert(0, item);
```

which works fine.
[image: Solution of my problem]

I want to know how can I do the above work using LINQ in a single statement? Or is it possible to do that in a single statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try an initial  ordering by whether the tenant number is "Any" (note that `false` comes before `true` by default, so you'll need to make it descending):

```
busConfigurationService.GetTenantsOverview()
                       .TenantsOverview
                       .Cast<TenantOverview>()
                       .Select(t => new { t.TenantId, t.Tenantnumber })
                       .OrderByDescending(t => t.Tenantnumber == "Any")
                       .ThenBy(t => t.Tenantnumber)
                       .ToList()
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an OrderBy and then a ThenBy

```
yourCurrentQuery.OrderBy(t => t.Tenantnumber == "Any" ? 0 : 1)
                .ThenBy(t => t.Tenantnumber);
```

[Ani's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14918378/414076) exhibits mostly the same technique and will certainly work. However, I generally do not prefer relying upon booleans for my ordering, as I find it not immediately intuitive. I do not expect that all will share my same hangup.